# Can I run Android Studio (Android SDK emulator) in a Microsoft hyper-v virtual machine?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, hyper-v

Can I run Android Studio and Android SDK emulator in a Microsoft hyper-v virtual machine? Please read carefully.

I already use Hyper-V a lot for other purposes. Now I need to develop a app for Android.

I've installed a new virtual machine (windows 10) and installed Android Studio. I cannot run the android emulator because it's lacking the 'intel HAXM software'.

I read a lot about that it's not possible to install Hyper-V NEXT to Android Studio, but non of the post actually say anything about installing in a Hyper-V machine.

Comment: Can you, in general, run a virtual machine inside hyper v?  Because that's essentially what you're doing

Comment: "Can I run Android Studio in a Microsoft hyper-v virtual machine?" -- that should be OK. However, that is not your problem. "I cannot run the android emulator because it's lacking the 'intel HAXM software'." -- Android Studio is not your problem. The Android SDK emulator is your problem. The ARM emulator images may work inside your virtual machine, but they will be very slow. I doubt that the x86 emulator images will work inside your virtual machine. Either test your app on Android hardware, or try a third-party emulator, like Genymotion.

Comment: Understood, so in short the answer is: no ?!

Comment: Android Emulator support for Hyper-V acceleration is currently in preview.  This should remove the need to use Microsoft's android emulator, or run the emulator in a nested virtual machine.  See this blog for details: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2018/05/08/hyper-v-android-emulator-support/

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Refer to this link: 
[How to run Android Studio on Windows without disabling Hyper-V](http://www.itwriting.com/blog/9371-how-to-run-android-studio-on-windows-without-disabling-hyper-v.html)

The solution (if you do not want to disable Hyper-V) is to use Microsoft’s Android emulator, which is a free download [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/msft-android-emulator-vs.aspx).

In order to use this with Android Studio, you need to run the emulator first. Then, in Android Studio, go to `Run` > `Edit Configurations...` and select Show Device Chooser Dialog under Deployment Target Options.

Run your project, and select the VS Emulator, ignoring the invitation to “Turn off Hyper-V”.

Comment: I tried using your solution. But as soon as i want to run a Android emulator with the Microsoft emulator it gives me the same(-ish) error as when i try to run the Android emulator with Android studio. ( literally complains about incompatibility with Hyper-V ).

Do you have any other alternatives for this ?

Comment: https://www.visualstudio.com/zh-hans/vs/msft-android-emulator/?rr=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F

Comment: The VS android emulator is missing new API version. The bad news is, MS is not going to to publish new versions for it. Read this: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/278669/#Comment_278669

Comment: **For Android Studio developers** : Please go to the bottom of the post mentioned in the answer to download the standalone installer of Microsoft Android Emulator which can be used with Android Studio or click [this](https://aka.ms/vscomemudownload) link.

Comment: @JunleLi I'm not sure your comment is still valid (post Win10 Apr2018 update) ... I'm able to run a Pie Pixel 2 emulation via Hyper-V

Answer (score 11):

Hyper-V added support for nested virtualization in the Windows 10 Anniversary Update (released August 2016) and Windows Server 2016.  However, the only Microsoft-supported usage of nested virtualization is running *Hyper-V* within the VM, not HAXM.  From the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/nested-virtualization), "Virtualization applications other than Hyper-V are not supported in Hyper-V virtual machines, and are likely to fail."

That said, the [change log](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-windows) for the latest release of HAXM reports that Intel "Fixed an issue with Hyper-V nested virtualization support, which had prevented Android Emulator from booting."  So while it isn't supported by Microsoft, it seems running HAXM nested in a Hyper-V VM may be possible.

If that's the case, to get HAXM working in a Hyper-V VM, you will need to enable nesting for that VM.  Run this command on the VM while it is in the OFF state:

```
Set-VMProcessor -VMName <VMName> -ExposeVirtualizationExtensions $true
```

After that, you should be able to install the latest version of HAXM within the VM, allowing use of the Android Emulator.  Again, I haven't personally verified this, and it isn't supported by Microsoft, so your mileage may vary.

Full disclosure: I work at Microsoft on the Hyper-V team.

[Edit 7/2/2018]: Android Emulator support for Hyper-V acceleration was announced earlier this year, and is currently in preview.  See the [announcement](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2018/05/08/hyper-v-android-emulator-support/) post for details.

Comment: While it technically works, it's slow as hell. And won't use GPU. So...unusable.

Comment: @MihaMarkic That happens, if you are running the ARM-VM

Comment: For me the Android SDK Manager was not willing to install HAXM. You can download and install it by yourself here: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-intel-haxm. After this I had to set the GPU Emulator Mode in the settings of the VM to "auto" and the emulator worked in the VM.

Comment: Please do keep us updated if anything changes on this front.

Comment: Update: Earlier this year, we announced a preview for Hyper-V acceleration support for the Android Emulator (i.e. using Hyper-V instead of HAXM).  This eliminates the need to run the emulator nested in a VM.

See here for details: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2018/05/08/hyper-v-android-emulator-support/

Answer (score 8):

Microsoft posted a link to allow Hyper-V as hardware accelerator for android emulator run in windows.

[The link is here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/hardware-acceleration?tabs=vswin&pivots=windows)

Here is the instructions.

1. Enter **About** in the Windows search box.
2. Select **About your PC** in the search results.
3. Scroll down in the **About** dialog to the **Windows specifications** section.
4. Verify that the **Version** is at least **1803**.
5. Enter **windows features** in the Windows search box and make sure both **Hyper-V** and **Windows Hypervisor Platform** are checked.
6. Open SDK manager in Android Studio, make sure your Android Emulator version is at least **27.2.7**.
7. Restart your computer, and relaunch your Android Emulator in AVD Manager in Android Studio.

Comment: Thanks! It wasn't clear to me at first that I need to enable *two distinct* windows features; I had enabled only Hyper-V. I still don't understand what the difference between the two are though.

Answer (score 7):

**Confirmed**: Running Windows 10 version 1803, with Hyper-V and Windows Hypervisor platform enabled, Android Studio's Emulator works. I am using Android Studio 3.2.1 and Android Emulator 28.0.22.

Answer (score 3):

Just make sure before you start with the steps suggested by lotosbin you complete the following:

Open an admin command prompt and enter the following; then restart the emulator.

```
`reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Android SDK Tools" /v Path /d %localappdata%\Android\sdk`
```

Or update the registry manually:

1. In regedit, navigate to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node.
2. Create a new key named Android SDK Tools(if not there already).
3. Navigate to that key.
4. Create a new string value named Path. Set its value to the location of your Android SDK, which will be like C:\Users\YourName\AppData\Local\Android\sdk.

Comment: Why? What is this for? What happens if not?

Comment: It's actually answering another question. If you do what @lotsobin suggested https://stackoverflow.com/a/38090974/3647974 and you do not see the device showing up, you should try what is explained here.

Comment: On my machine I already had this registry entry with `path` string pointing to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk`. Do I still need to update this entry to AppData path in  your post?

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft has [announced](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2018/05/08/hyper-v-android-emulator-support/) a better solution

> Today, at Build 2018, we announced a preview of the Google Android
>   emulator that’s compatible with Hyper-V, available on the Windows 10
>   April 2018 Update. This enables developers with Hyper-V enabled on
>   their machines to use a hardware accelerated Android emulator, without
>   needing to switch to Intel’s HAXM hypervisor. Amazing work was done by
>   the Windows Hyper-V team, with help from the Xamarin team, to make to
>   this happen.

Answer (score 1):

Just to complement @lotosbin's answer and add an additional information. This information is regarding when you are trying to start your app in [Microsoft's standalone Android emulator](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/msft-android-emulator/) from Android Studio.

On the `Select Deployment Target` window there are two sections namely:

1. `Connected Devices` - It shows up physical android devices attached to your computer through USB port e.g. mobile, tablet if you want to deploy your app into an actual device
2. `Available Virtual Devices` - It shows up Android virtual emulators which are build from specific device definition e.g. `Nexus 5X API 28`

Interestingly, Microsoft's Android emulator shows up in `Connected Devices` section. So Android Studio treats Microsoft's Android emulator as a physical device instead even though it is a virtual emulator only. Please see the screenshot below:

[image]

Additionally, you can check the health and current status of Microsoft's Android emulator inside Hyper-V Manager also as shown in below screenshot:

[image]