# Cordova app emulates fine on Android in Ubuntu but get blank screen on Android in Windows 10

Tags: android, cordova, ubuntu, android-emulator, windows-10

I have been given an cordova application that was originally developed on Ubuntu for Android and this app runs when I use the cordova emulate command from the terminal.

However - when I use the very same application on my Windows 10 machines and attempt to get this running using the same command I simply get a blank screen?

Android has been setup correctly as I am able to create a fresh 'HelloWorld' Cordova app and this opens both fine within my emulator and on my actual hardware device.

I have removed the platforms directory and tried to redownload the Android platform using the cordova platform add android command but still have no joy??

Any ideas of what I am doing wrong... I am using the latest versions of cordova, node etc..

```
Cordova 6.3.1
Node v4.4.7
```

Comment: Just a hunch but is Hyper-V turned on. If it is turn it off and try again -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35293574/can-i-run-android-studio-android-sdk-emulator-in-a-microsoft-hyper-v-virtual-m

Comment: Have you also removed the plugins ? Have you looked in the console to see if there is any errors ? (logcat and chrome)

Comment: i'll try removing the plugins and getting back to you