# Running AVD(android virtual Devices)in esxi 5.5 type-I hypervisor

Tags: android, virtualization

I am facing nuisance regards to setup of AVD(android virtual Device).As mentioned in other posts and in google search on this issue not worked for me.Now I explain about error.
i)  I have installed Android virtual Device in esxi-5.5 type 1 hypervisor on VM(running Windows server 2012).

ii) When i try to run android image in AVD,it prompt for error that "android emulator is incompatible with hyper-v " under android studio 2.3.
iii) it suggested to disable/turnoff  hyper-v using **"bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off"** command.which i did.
iv) I am still facing same issue after running command and checked it is off(hyper-v).I have no clue why i see same error,and no joy after struggling to make it work from last 4 hours. please anyone there who are available to help,i would appreciate.
best regard's
emmu

Comment: Have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35293574/can-i-run-android-studio-android-sdk-emulator-in-a-microsoft-hyper-v-virtual-m

Comment: it makes sense now, what i was hunting from last 5 hours. thankx.