# Android Studio not detecting Microsoft Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, emulation, ms-android-emulator

I installed Microsoft's Android Emulator from [here](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/msft-android-emulator/) which can now work without disabling Hyper-V on Windows 10. I was following the instructions in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38090974/465053) post and everything was working smooth until yesterday. I was successfully able to debug my app in MS android emulator.

[image]

Today morning I closed the emulator and started it again. Now, When I start running the app to test it then the MS Android emulator is not showing up in `Select Deployment Target` window of Android Studio as below. `Nexus 5X API 28` emulator visible under `Available Virtual Devices` is Google's Android emulator which doesn't work with Hyper-V enabled due to reasons mentioned [here](https://superuser.com/q/1209266/374397).

[image]

I've already launched the MS Android simulator and it is up and running:

[image]

I can see it running in Hyper-V as well as shown below:

[image]

Not sure what happened suddenly and it stopped working altogether. Can anyone suggest me the reason behind it or I'm missing something?

Comment: Even genny motion emulator didn't used to show up in Android studio unless you installed a plugin for it

Comment: How to install the corresponding plugin in Android Studio?

Comment: I am not sure if there is any plugin for Microsoft Android Emulator . A quick search for plugins did not give me any result

Answer (score 1):

If it didn't detected by IDE, try to rerun the emulator and check if it is detecting again or not.

Also, you can try this too:

> Tools -> Android -> Enable ADB Integration

If it is already enabled, try to disable and re enable it, seems like this works most of the times.

---

**EDIT:** You may want to check:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38788436/4409113

Changing the *value Path* then running following commands:

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

Might help.

Comment: I don't have `Tools` > `Android` menu in my IDE. I'm using Android Studio v3.1.3 for Windows.

Comment: Try the next solution, by changing the path. I have edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I happened to resolve it by chance. Sharing my experience in case it helps someone in future.

Initially what I was doing is as below:

1. Start Visual Studio Emulator for Android application which contains the list all the device profiles.
2. Choose an appropriate device profile and install it.
3. Run the installed profile and launch the emulator.
4. Start Android studio, open the project and launch the app.

I simply reversed the above steps to resolve my issue. First close everything including Android Studio, emulators, device profile window etc.:

1. At first, start Android studio, open the project and hit `Run app` button to show `Select Deployment Target` window.
2. Now, start Visual Studio Emulator for Android application which contains the list of all the device profiles.
3. Choose an appropriate device profile and install it.
4. Run the installed profile and launch the emulator. Wait for the Android operating system to get started fully.
5. The `Connected Devices` section in `Select Deployment Target` window would refresh on its own to start showing Microsoft's Android Emulator.

Answer (score 0):

The adb.exe can be seen as an infected file by antivirius software.  So need to exclude once reinstated.