# Can you run the Android emulator in Ubuntu running inside Hyper-V?

Tags: android-studio, ubuntu, android-emulator, virtual-machine, hyper-v

I have set up an Ubuntu VM through Hyper-V in Windows. In this Ubuntu I am trying to create an Android Studio Emulator but I literally cannot start any of the emulators because all the images give this error:

`Your CPU does not support required features (VT-x or SVM)`

My questions:

1. **What does this error mean?**
2. **How do I resolve it?**

Notes:

- Is it because I am trying to run an emulator (VM) inside an VM?
- Below that it says `We recommend these Google Play images because this device is compatible with Google Play`, does this mean anything?
- I am very new to Hyper-V, Ubuntu and Android Studio
- I don't have an abnormally weak laptop so I don't think it is hardware issues
- Here is a similar question, but this person is using a Windows VM, I am using an Ubuntu VM [Can I run Android Studio (Android SDK emulator) in a Microsoft hyper-v virtual machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35293574/can-i-run-android-studio-android-sdk-emulator-in-a-microsoft-hyper-v-virtual-m)

Comment: It's because the CPU doesn't support Hyper V, and in this case, you need to look away from the system CPU - it isn't important. It means the emulated CPU doesn't support VT-x. I'm not sure how to turn it on (or for that matter if you can, and it depends on the VM)

Answer (score 0):

To put this simply for you, Hyper-V in your CPU is already being used by Ubuntu. You cannot expect Hyper-V to be available for other emulators as well. Try USB debugging in some android phone. It is better and more RAM and power efficient.